# Can't Install Eclipse Juno CheckStyle Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I heard that a good plugin for metrics for Java Eclipse was the CheckStyle plugin. So I try and follow [their instructions](http://bit.ly/14NWRCY) on how to install it, but I keep getting the following:

[image]

Can someone kindly point out how I can fix this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you access http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update/ in your browser?

Comment: Yep, i get two xml files in the Browser !

Comment: There's a dot after the URL you're using, maybe that's causing an issue?  Or else, try again, maybe there was a temporary issue with the server.

Comment: No the dot at the end was being added by Eclipse when it printed out the error. But just tried again, and it works now ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fully know why it didn't work. There was an Eclipse Juno update that I had to run. For the update to happen, I had to run Eclipse as Administrator. Then ran the update, and it worked, i.e. it updated successfully.

I then ran the CheckStyle plug-in install as instructed on their website, and it worked fine.

Hope this helps.